# Round up in 30 min (nearest half-hour) increments:

Tags: java, datetime, math, routes

What is the most efficient way (in Java)  to round an integer in 30 increments. My output will be an Integer:

Here is my code that returns minutes in integer.

```
long different = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
int idiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(different) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(different));
```

Now I want to round up this integer. For example:

> Any number <= 30 = round up to 30:
>
> Any number between 31 to 60 = round up to 60
>
> Any number between 61 to 90 = round up to 90
>
> Any number between 91 to 120 = round up to 120
>
> Any number between 121 to 150 = round up to 150

Comment: note that 120 to 160 is 40

Comment: Are you sure you want 30 rounded up to 60?  Shouldn't that be 31-60?  Based on your description, 60 is both left at 60 AND rounded up to 90.  The problem statement is inconsistent as written.  Also, I think 120-160 should be 120-150. Is this a typo?

Comment: Jim - you are right. 30 should stay at 30, no change. Only when between 31-60.

Answer (score 3):

Add one less than the group you want, then divide and multiple.. so for 30 do

```
((value + 29) / 30) * 30
```

This assumes you want 0 to stay at 0, 30 to stay at 30...

Comment: The question is ambiguous, but this is probably what the OP intends.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
x = ((x+30)/30) * 30;
```

Examples :

```
((15+30)/30)*30 == (45/30)*30 == 1*30 == 30
((30+30)/30)*30 == (60/30)*30 == 2*30 == 60
((47+30)/30)*30 == (77/30)*30 == 2*30 == 60
...
```

EDIT :

After the OP changed the requirements (30 should stay 30) :

```
x = ((x+29)/30) * 30;
```

Examples :

```
((15+29)/30)*30 == (44/30)*30 == 1*30 == 30
((30+29)/30)*30 == (59/30)*30 == 1*30 == 30
((47+29)/30)*30 == (76/30)*30 == 2*30 == 60
...
```