# Rounding calendar time to nearest 5 mins

Tags: java, calendar, rounding

The code below works well for rounding java calendar time to the nearest 15mins, however how can I change the code below to allow for rounding to the closest 5mins clock mark.

Code:

```
int unroundedMinutes = isha_jamaat_cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int mod = unroundedMinutes % 15;
System.out.println("#######mod: " + mod);
isha_jamaat_cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mod < 8 ? -mod : (15-mod));
```

Comment: Change `15` to `5` ...

Comment: Change  15 to 5 on the second and fourth lines, and change 8 to  3 on the fourth line perhaps?

Comment: not that easy mate, what about this?? it also needs to be changed mod < 8 ? -mod : (15-mod)

Comment: Yes, I told you how to do that.

Comment: I should not be getting voted down @MadProgrammer

Comment: oh yes you should.

Comment: Getting voted down is one thing people can do, and how do YOU know that specific user did so?  Note: I did NOT vote down or up here, just pointing it out.  Better perhaps to ask WHY people are doing so.

Comment: now i got -3 hhhh

Comment: well, it is consistent with what you have been receiving on the majority of your questions on stackoverflow.  You must have a special skill for posting questions that rarely receive a score above zero.

Comment: Casual  suggestion, take the code you have, attempt what is suggested THEN ask/revise with "I am attempting to round time to nearest 5 minutes....(show code attempted) then What have I done wrong here?"

Comment: @Ossama Not the down voter - and that's not your call - Rounding time has been asked many times before so far all I see is "I have found some code can anyone modify for me" - no attempt to solve the problem yourself. Should we also discuss the choice of `Calendar` in 2018

Comment: @Ossama The same question/answer you took the above code also demonstrated using `LocalDateTime` `LocalDateTime lastQuarter = time.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).plusMinutes(15 * (time.getMinute() / 15));` which would be significantly easier to modify

Comment: Thanks mate, you may need to speed feed me edits to the suggestion you just made. noobie here

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Duplicate and similar: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3553964/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27082097/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25552023/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37613071/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49020441/642706) & more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this code but i believe it should work.

```
int unroundedMinutes = isha_jamaat_cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int mod = unroundedMinutes % 5;
isha_jamaat_cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mod < 3 ? -mod : (5-mod));
```

The basic idea is to check whether the current time is nearest to the next or the previous 5 minutes clock mark and adjusting the added value based on this.

Comment: Can we not use `Calendar` anymore

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: it's cos he took the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3553994/1280060 (written in 2010)